# How to fit a rectangular wave to a signal?

Tags: wave, discrete-wavelet-transform

I have some binary data that mostly comes under the form of a rectangular signal. In order to "idealize" my signal I would like to fit a rectangular wave that best represent my signal (Here I mean, in lack of a better idea, minimizing the sum of squared errors). So I tried that and it miserably failed.

Then I thought I would try to fit a regular square wave to a square wave and then add a layer of complexity to get the rectangular wave. It failed.

Then after some research I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591123/fitting-a-signal-to-a-square-wave-form-using-lmfit) in which it is cleverly suggested that one should use a soft (i.e differentiable) square signal since it is needed to be able to differentiate the MSE (Mean Squared Error) in order to perform optimization (via BFGS for instance). So I tried that :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy


def square_fun(t, pulsation, delay):
    return (1.0 + scipy.signal.square(pulsation * (t - delay))) / 2.0


def soft_square_fun(t, amplitude, slope, pulsation, delay):
    return amplitude * (1 + np.tanh(slope * np.cos(pulsation * (t - delay)))) / 2.0


def soft_square_mse(X, t, y):
    amplitude, slope, pulsation, delay = X
    MSE = np.square(y - soft_square_fun(t, amplitude, slope, pulsation, delay)).mean()
    return MSE


t = np.arange(0, 1000, 1)
amplitude = 10.0
slope = 10.0
pulsation = 2 * np.pi * (1 / 50)
delay = 112
objective_data = square_fun(t, pulsation, delay)

p0 = (amplitude, slope, pulsation * 1.1, delay / 2)


bounds = [
    (amplitude / 10, amplitude * 20),
    (slope / 10, slope * 10),
    (delay / 10, delay * 10),
    (pulsation / 10, pulsation * 10),
]
optim_res = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    soft_square_mse,
    p0,
    (t, objective_data),
    method="BFGS",
    bounds=bounds,
    options={"tol": 1e-25, "gtol": 1e-50, "maxiter": 5000, "disp": True},
)

amplitude_ret = optim_res.x[0]
slope_ret = optim_res.x[1]
pulsation_ret = optim_res.x[2]
delay_ret = optim_res.x[3]


plt.figure()
plt.title("objective function vs fitted function")
plt.plot(t.flatten(), objective_data.flatten())
plt.plot(
    t.flatten(),
    soft_square_fun(t, amplitude_ret, slope_ret, pulsation_ret, delay_ret).flatten(),
)
plt.legend(["objective function", "fitted function"])
plt.show()
```

If you don't want to run the code here is an example of how comically bad it performs :
[image]

Of course if one is trying to fit strictly square waves it is possible to use the DFT although what you are doing if fitting a sine to a square wave via a FFT in order to fit a square wave, which seems like an overkill. But it wouldn't even work on my data since I have a rectangular wave and not a square one.

Is there something I am missing? Some crazy wavelet transform that would solve it? Any help is welcome.

Here are some of the requested raw data signals :

[image]
[image]
[image]

The downward and upward spikes are due to a preprocessing problem that I cannot undo in short amount of time.

As it was requested here is a hand drawn example of how it might look like. Note that since I could not minimize the error function it might be non representative of what it would actually look like:
[image]

Comment: I would help to clarify what exactly is your input is? If it's really a clean binary signal, the problem seems trivial so there must be some sort of contamination. What it is and how bad is it ?

Comment: @Hilmar unfortunately I have problem with my data but basically picture noisy data with  varying period, on duration, off duration and noise (some additional zeroes). But besides that how is the clean signal a trivial problem? the problem is interesting to me by itself.

Comment: By trivial I mean: identify the 1s and the 0s. Count the number of consecutive 1s and consecutive zeros. That gives you the period and the duty cycle. The difference between the average 1 (High) level and the average 0 (Low) level is the amplitude. Whenever you transition from a 0 to a 1 you start a new period. That's your phase. So (in my opinion) this is only difficult if you can't reliably distinguish between 1s and 0s (or High and Low). If you can't, we need to understand the nature of the contamination. Fixing this will solve the other issue as well

Comment: Describing it differently: find the transitions from low to high. The height of the transition is the amplitude, the difference between  two consecutive transitions is the period and the absolute position of the transition (relative to t = 0) gives you the phase. The difference between Low-to-High and High-to-Low is the duty cycle,

Comment: @Hilmar Ok I get it now! Unfortunately my data is a bit messy and that's why I want to simplify it with a rectangular wave identification in order to be reliably able to count the ones and zeros, to see the transitions and use this information for other purposes. That's actually why I thought least squares was a good idea in the beginning.

Comment: NokiYola, could you please edit your question to explain in detail the things you mention in your comments here? We still don't know what you mean with "noisy data", "data is a bit messy". Less handwaving please, more actual description, examples,  and so on. All you've given us is code and a picture of something that does *not* seem to represent your actual data. We can't help you when we don't understand.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added some data but I am really interested in knowing why I couldn't fit a rectangular wave or how to do so.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you maybe "draw" on that top one what you would want to get after fitting?

Comment: By “top one” I mean top of the added plots of raw signals

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding the figures. I still don't understand what you mean with "fitting a rectangular wave"; you're using that term as if it was a specific agreed-upon technical term, but sadly, it's not, and nobody but you knows what you mean with it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I apologize. I meant fitting as scipy means it in its "curve_fit" method or Tensorflow and sklearn mean it in their "fit" methods, i.e minimizing an error function (often, but not always, the sum of squared residuals). In our context it would mean adjusting the phase, period and cycle duty of a rectangle wave to minimize the sum of the squared residuals. In my work and with my engineer friends people use it quite a lot. Since I saw a lot of content about least squares on this forum I thought people would be more used to it.

Comment: @Jdip look at my answer to Marcus Müller and the edit. I tried to draw what you ask but it was hand-made so be gentle!

Comment: hm, a square wave is not differentiable, and typically the difference to such a function isn't, either. I don't think the usual optimization methods are applicable to *your* problem, no matter how much your friends use it for different problems!

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you read the question again, you'll see that I tried with a differentiable (quasi) square function to go around this problem. Also, as far as I know, the differentiability of the data is irrelevant, but maybe you could show me some material to defend your case? I'm genuinely interested if you have some. That being said could you quit being aggressive please? I'm honestly trying to answer each comment the most factual way I can here and I don't think I was rude or disrespectful to anyone so far. Maybe it's not enough for you but I'm doing my best.

Comment: I would do this differently: something like looking at the proportion of 1s over a moving window of size you should define and experiment with. If that proportion is above a certain threshold, set your “fit” to 1. Otherwise to 0.

Comment: @Jdip yes I guess if I can get the overall cyclic duty and if I find a way to obtain the number of periods (via FFT maybe) I could get a wave that kinda represent my data

Comment: Not sure I get where you’re going with this… it really seems like you’re making this a harder problem than it is. Would you be able to share some of that data?

Comment: @Jdip you mean something else than the curves I already showed you? Since the time I posted I went around my problem and to be honest now I'm interested in why the fit failed (from a mathematical perspective).

Comment: I meant share the actual data so that I can play around with it. But if you’ve dropped it, no bother ;)